# Can you write files in a different directory using PHP?

Tags: php, filesystems, localhost

If I have a PHP-driven CMS on `C:\wamp\www\cms` (alias `http://localhost/cms`) and I want to write `log.txt` to say `Z:\MySite\logs`, is that possible using PHP? `file_put_contents()`? What if `Z:\` is a network drive?

### What I've tried

`file_put_contents("Z:/MySite/logs/log.txt",$log);`

And I got:

`Warning: file_put_contents(Z:/Mysite/logs/log.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\cms\compiler.php on line 96`

**edit:**

`Z:/MySite/logs` directory does exist and I have r/w access, though it is on a network drive. (My intention is to dev on my local Apache (C:/) installation then output a preview directly to my network (Z:/) drive so my teammates can view it.) The warning I get (above) seems to indicate it is searching for the Z:\MySite[...] directory *inside* my C:/wamp[...] directory. I'm stuck.

Comment: You can write them anywhere PHP has write permissions.  Just like anything else that can write files.

Comment: Does z/mysite/logs exist? (and do you have permission to view?)

Comment: Sorry, updated the question but put the wrong output... just fixed it. @Wooble I'm sure I'm just missing something but don't know what... not very experienced with filesystem functions.

Comment: You can't write to directories that don't exist.  PHP won't build a full path for you if you try it, it will just throw an error instead.  You'll either have to manually create the directory or write PHP code that will check for its existence and create it if it doesn't exist.  I'd recommend the former for now.

Comment: @MrJack Yes, `z:/MySite/logs` exists, and I do have permission to view... but what I'm gleaning from my output is that it's trying to find that in my C:\wamp... directory

Comment: Sorry, I guess I assumed the answer was something more complex, like using an `opendir` or `chdir` or something. I've updated my question with context.

Comment: what happens if you try writing it like this: Z:\\MySite\\logs\\log.txt (with escaped slashes - because windows is strange often)

Comment: @MrJack yeah, just tried it as `file_put_contents("Z:/MySite/logs/log.txt")`, `..Z:\/MySite\/logs\/log.txt`, and `..Z:\\MySite\\logs\\log.txt` with all the same output... "No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\MySite\compiler.php"... it is still looking in C:\ drive. How do I get it to _not_ look in C:\ drive?

Comment: Maybe this here will help: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=25805 (but it is from linux to windows stuff so it might not help)

Comment: From that it seems you cant connect to a network drive with a null-session. Was an interesting read, try saving in a local drive to see if it works, if so, that may very well be the problem you are facing.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I'm not gleaning anything in there specific to my issue, but man, thanks for digging. I'm gathering from your responses that 1) it should be possible to write to a different drive letter, 1.b) even if that drive is a network drive, 2) `file_put_contents` should be all I need, and 3) the output I'm getting is unexpected. I was hoping it was just that I missed some function I should have used.

Comment: Actually ive only done it with fopen and fwrite on both windows and linux. But now that I am used to linux I aint ever going back to windows. (changed because when updating to prod some things wouldnt work due to the dev. not being in the same environment)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57765/discussion-between-philtune-and-mr-jack).